# How to avoid timeout on a form submission in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

In short, I have build a form to import data from a csv file. But because I do a lot of data verification and converting in the view on form submission then I get a 504 Gateway Time-out when importing a long csv file. So what to do?

I have thought of handing the import after form submission over to a celery task, but then the user will not get the error if one happens.

Comment: Either: 1. execute async (celery) and send mail to user when something fails 2. set gateway timeout to something larger. You cant have it both.

Comment: @RickyA Well if I set up some ajax call to keep the gateway open I might have a 3rd version. Or maybe redirect people to a waiting page, and then give them a result page in the end I guess